# How to track that the specific Thread is Completed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I  am using the MultiThread application.

```
    ThreadStart thSA = new ThreadStart(saBroker.SearchContract);
                    DTThread threadSA = new DTThread(thSA, WaitForSA);
                    brokerThreads.Add(threadSA);

 ThreadStart thSA1 = new ThreadStart(saBroker1.SearchContract);
                    DTThread threadSA1 = new DTThread(thSA1, WaitForSA1);
                    brokerThreads.Add(threadSA1);
           brokerThreads.StartAll();
```

Now i have scenario where i have to perform specific task after the  **threadSA1** completed.
So, how can i track that the specific Thread Complete.

Please Help...

Answer (score 2):

What is `DTThread` class? If this is class inherited from `Thread`, you can wait for it with `Join()` method:

```
ThreadStart thSA = new ThreadStart(saBroker.SearchContract);
                    DTThread threadSA = new DTThread(thSA, WaitForSA);
                    brokerThreads.Add(threadSA);

ThreadStart thSA1 = new ThreadStart(saBroker1.SearchContract);
                    DTThread threadSA1 = new DTThread(thSA1, WaitForSA1);
                    brokerThreads.Add(threadSA1);
           brokerThreads.StartAll();
threadSA1.Join();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now i have scenario where i have to perform specific task after the
>   threadSA1 completed. So, how can i track that the specific Thread
>   Complete.

How about using a delegate callback?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wait and notify tactic to perform synchronization between the threads such that the main thread is halted using a blocking instruction and then just before *threadSA1* completes it wakes the blocked thread.

Take a look at this article for more information, which I think will help you:
http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/12/thread-and-sync-in-c/

In the article the author uses:

```
     mre.WaitOne();
```

and

```
    mre.Set();
```

for waiting and notifying respectively